# How can Angular 2 load an SVG image?

Tags: svg, angular

I tried this code in an Angular 2 template:

```
<ul class="products">
  <li *ngFor="#p of products">
    <svg width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
         <g>
            <title>{{p.Name}}</title>
            <image xlink:href="http://somewhere.com/{{p.Picture1}}"
                   id="svg_21" height="176.731579" width="117" y="28" x="32" />
        </g>
    </svg></li></ul>
```

And got the error:

```
 EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
 Can't bind to '@xlink:href' since it isn't a known native property 
 <image [ERROR ->]xlink:href="http://somewhere.com/{{p.Picture1}}"
        id="svg_21" height="176.731579" widt"): AppComponent@13:37
```

I tried to use this, which is definitely on the right path:

```
attr.xlink:href="http://somewhere.com/{{p.Picture1}}"
```

but in using that, I instead get an error of cannot find `my-app`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seconds after posting the question, I found the answer:

```
<image *ngIf="p.Picture1" attr.xlink:href="http://somewhere.com/{{p.Picture1}}" />
```

Apparently if `p.Picture1` is empty, it invalidates html or SVG more likely in such a way that `my-app` is not found, which follows.